# headphones not working ( HP Spectre x360 Convertible 13-w0XX)

Tags: sound, headphones, soundcard, external-soundcard

I just got ubuntu 16LTS, but now when I put headphones in they won't work, the speakers work fine though, http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=462a1ea0e736a38ee69fe53626cf23907f3b1ceb, thats my ALSA link if that helps.

If someone could help that would be great

Comment: Have you checked if the headphones are actually selected?

Comment: Yer when I go into the sound card mixer its not muted and the normal mixer says that its selected